# NSArray to NSString....Some Crashes occur

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have some problem with converting NSArray to NSString.

Here is the code.

```
- (void)createStringWithArray:(NSArray *)arr_1 andTheOtherArray:(NSArray *)are_2
{
     NSString *outputString = @"Start";

     if (arr_1) {
         for (Object *object in arr_1) {
             outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n(%f, %f)", object.value1, object.value2];
         }
         outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"\nArray 1 End"];
     }
     if (arr_2) {
         for (Object *object in arr_2) {
             outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n(%f, %f)", object.value1, object.value2];
         }
         outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"\nArray 2 End"];
     }

     NSLog(@"%@", outputString);
}
```

There are 48 objects and 1568 objects in each are_1 and are_2.

I cannot find any problem with iPhone Simulator
but, the application is crashed with no logs with the iPad mini and iPhone5 device.
It occurs on the second loop function.

I guess there must be memory issue, but I don't know what is wrong exactly.

Please help on this.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint for break on throw for all exceptions. Connect your device to your computer and launch the app through XCode. Show us: the stack trace at the time of crash, output on console.

Comment: in your params you have are_2 instead arr_2

Comment: How do you know it's occurring in the second loop if you have no logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString`. The string should be mutable

```
 - (void)createStringWithArray:(NSArray *)arr_1 andTheOtherArray:(NSArray *)arr_2
    {
        NSMutableString *outputString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Start"];

        if (arr_1) {
            for (Object *object in arr_1) {

               [outputString appendFormat:@"\n(%f, %f)", object.value1, object.value2];
            }
            [outputString  appendString:@"\nArray 1 End"];
        }
        if (arr_2) {
            for (Object *object in arr_2) {
                [outputString appendFormat:@"\n(%f, %f)", object.value1, object.value2];
            }
            [outputString appendString:@"\nArray 2 End"];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", outputString);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

in method you declare that you have two arrays (arr_1 and are_2) but in IFs you are using arr_1 and arr_2, so compiler should show error even if you not execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning botharrays to a single variable `outputSting`. make it as different variable and concat them. Also take care of passing parameters inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of items in your arrays then you could be consuming a lot of memory. Each time you have:

```
outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingFormat:@"..."];
```

You are creating new strings over and over but the memory used by the old strings is still in use. You can't release this memory manually because you don't own it, it gets released the next time the autorelease pool is drained, but because the pool is not drained anywhere in your method you run the risk of running out of memory.

This can be fixed by simply using a mutable string instead.

```
- (void)createStringWithArray:(NSArray *)arr_1 andTheOtherArray:(NSArray *)are_2
{
     NSString *outputString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Start"];

     if (arr_1) {
         for (Object *object in arr_1)
             [outputString appendFormat:@"\n(%f, %f)", object.value1, object.value2];
         [outputString appendString:@"\nArray 1 End"];
     }

     if (arr_2) {
         for (Object *object in arr_2)
             [outputString appendFormat:@"\n(%f, %f)", object.value1, object.value2];
         [outputString appendString:@"\nArray 2 End"];
     }

     NSLog(@"%@", outputString);
}
```